# django delete a case if not answered

Tags: python, django

[image: delete exprimer une seule idee if there is nothing written]I have an open question in django in which the participant can respond giving different ideas.
I want to save the answer if something is written in the case; otherwise delete the case. Until now I have:

```
answer={}
if question.is answered(participant):
    answer= question.get contributions(participant)
else:
    question.delete()
```

Comment: What is your question? Is your code not working? Does it give an error?

Comment: I dont understand how to do it. I need to delete the exprimer une seule idee part if there is nothing writteN

Comment: can you show some actual code instead of pseudo-code? for instance you can show us the code for the model this form refers to. the view's code would also be useful.

Comment: def get(self, request, page, url_base="/slide/", participant_urlid=None, usergroup_urlid=None):
        self.page = page

        answer=answer.objects.create(answer=answer)
        if question.is answered(participant):
            answer=  Participant.objects.add(answer=answer)
        else:

        if usergroup_urlid:
            usergroup = get_object_or_404(UserGroup, urlid=usergroup_urlid)
        # from data base
        else:
            usergroup = UserGroup.objects.filter(is_active=True).first()  # can be None
        request.session["usergroup"] = usergroup